# Is the set of limit points of the real numbers the real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, I can find an $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $x$ that when I intersect it with $\mathbb{R}$, I'll get a set containing something other than $x$, so I think my conjecture is true. Is this reasoning correct?

Would this also suggest that $[0,\infty)$ must have the set of its limit points to be $L=[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the limit points for $\mathbb{R}$ and $L$ are just themselves.

But your reasoning is a bit off.

For each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and *for all* neighbourhoods $E$ of $x$, there is a $y \in \mathbb{R}, y\neq x$ such that $y\in E$. It is not a question about you being able to find a neighbourhood.

A general fact is that $x$ is a limit point of a set $S$ if and only if it is in the closure of $S \setminus \{x\}$.

Comment: Also, a set $S$ is equal to its set of limit points iff $\{x\}$ is not open for any $x\in S$.